# How to decrypt pdf base 64 in xcode?

Tags: pdf, xcode4, base64

I 'm developing an app in xcode , I have a service that sends a PDF file encrypted in base64 to the app, the question i have is how to decrypt the file and if there is any library that allows me to view the file?

Comment: Why are you Base64-encoding the PDF in the first place? Can't you send it as it is? Or is it a third party service that you don't control?

Comment: In fact the service was originally designed for Android and web , so that the service sends coded in this way, if there are other ways to show the pdf can do it, please tell me, i can open another web service for that if is necesary.

Comment: It's just terribly inefficient. Base64 is only necessary when you have to pass binary data (such as PDF) via a channel that only allows plain text. Base64 adds size and incurs encoding/decoding overhead. Meanwhile. HTTP is perfectly capable of transferring binary data.

Comment: Ok, so what are the alternatives i have??? How can i get the pdf file??? or in this case what do you do???

Comment: Send the PDF from the service as-is :) On the iOS side, read up on CGPDFDocument. And most importantly, don't hesitate to LOOK STUFF UP. StackOverflow is not a programming school.